# What is the correct syntax for this query?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT address, phone FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE @0","%name.text%"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT address,phone FROM Contacts WHERE name LIKE '%@%%'", name.text];
```